# ionic1 error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework

i am making a application using ionic1 and angularjs1.

Today, when i execute `ionic serve` command in terminal. then i got following error.

```
js@js:peoject$ ionic serve
[INFO] Starting server: --port=8100 --p=8100 --livereload-port=35729 --r=35729 --address=0.0.0.0 - Ctrl+C to cancel
TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
```

from last 2-3 months there was no any issue but today suddenly i faced with this issue.

My ionic version is 3.3.0

Is there anything update on ionic or what else? i dont understand.

Comment: I'm also facing this error.
It was running good yesterday, Just updated ionic now and this error start coming

Comment: @MUHAMMADSOBAN Please review my answer. It will solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a lot and the solutions is very simple.

My previous version of ionic was 2.2.0

So, i downgrade the ionic version.

First, remove the ionic, then reinstall with your old version.

```
harish@harish: sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
harish@harish: sudo npm install -g ionic@2.2.0
```

or

```
harish@harish: sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
harish@harish: sudo npm install -g ionic@2.2.3
```

or

```
harish@harish: sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
harish@harish: sudo npm install -g ionic@2.3.0
```

Whatever the version is, just uninstall your latest ionic and install your old version.

Then the issue is solved.

Comment: yes, it is perfect. it save my day. i tried a lot.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error downgrade your ionic version.

```
sudo npm install -g ionic@2.2.3
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

reinstall the ionic

```
npm uninstall -g cordova ionic
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

this solved my same problem